React-native-fs unable to fetch files(.mp3) in mobile internal storage
code :


App. tsx :

import React from 'react' import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native' import Home from './src/pages/Home'  function App() {   return (     <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>       <Home />     </View>   ) }  export default App 

Home. js :

import React, { use effect, useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, } from 'react-native'
import { theme } from '../themes/themes'
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const Home = () => {



    const [FolderData, setFolderData] = useState([]);

    const fetchMP3FilesFromPhoneInternalStorage = async () => {
        try {
            const downloadFolderPath = RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath
            const files = await RNFS.readDir(downloadFolderPath);
            files.forEach(f => console.log(f.name))
        } catch {
            console.log('error occur')
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMP3FilesFromPhoneInternalStorage()

    }, [])
    return (
        <View style={styles.body}>
            {
                FolderData.map((data, index) => {
                    return (
                        <View key={index}>
                            <Text>{data}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
                })
            }
        </View>
    )
}

export default Home

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    body: {
        backgroundColor: theme[0].primary,
        flex: 1,
    }
})

and also I have added permission in androidMainfest.xml
androidMainfest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

</manifest>
//It only fetches the folders, but not files inside download directory.
output:





I'm new to react native, I'm trying to build my offline music player app I want to use local mp3 files when I used to fetch them by using react-native-fs it only fetches folders but not files, I am just stuck at this point please help me out of this Thanks in advance.

Android version of used device?

Who created those files?

@blackapps The Android version is 13,
I downloaded those files on internet.

For Android 13+ devices to list and read media files you need a different READ permission.

downloaded those files on internet. ? You mean you downloaded them from the internet to your device. And it was not your app who did that.

Yes, It's my device, I downloaded those mp3 files from the internet, and those files are located in download directory. Could you please tell that read permission to fetch media files.

READ_MEDIA_AUDIO.
